# What are the "garment thin" and the "prize" in the song "The Ballad of the Shape of Things to Come"?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics

From the song "The Ballad of the Shape of Things to Come" (lyrics [link](https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/1142348/Blossom+Dearie/The+Ballad+of+the+Shape+of+Things)):

> Triangular is the piece of pie I eat to ease my sorrow
> Triangular is the hatchet blade I plan to hide tomorrow
> Triangular the relationship which now has ceased to be
> And triangular is the **garment thin**
> That fastens on with a safety pin
> To a **prize I had no wish to win**
> It's a lasting memory
> That my true love gave to me

I'm a non-native speaker, and the meaning is unclear to me. What could be this "garmet thin" of triangular shape? And what is the "prize I had no wish to win"?

I feel that the two might be related so I clumped them into a single question.

P.S. Who is the author of the ballad? I haven't found the author. The Kingston Trio?

Comment: Your link goes to a song that doesn't contain the lyrics you quote.

Comment: BTW, I think the garment is a diaper, and the prize "I had no wish to win" is a baby.

Comment: @Robusto - thank you! You might post this as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting [Robusto's comment](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/15804/what-are-the-garment-thin-and-the-prize-in-the-song-the-ballad-of-the-shape#comment25008_15804) to an answer:

The garment is a diaper, and the prize "I had no wish to win" is a baby.